# Session and Cookies not working on Windows Azure Cloud environment

Tags: session, cookies, web-config, azure

I have migrated a website to cloud, which works perfectly on my local machine using the Compute and Storage Emulators.

However, when I put it onto Windows Azure Cloud, the session and cookies are not working fine. Part of web.config file is given below.

```
<sessionState timeout="30"
              mode="SQLServer"
              sqlConnectionString="Server=sxxxxxxxxx.database.windows.net;User ID=xxxxx@sxxxxxxxxx;Password=MY_PASSWORD"
              cookieless="false"
              allowCustomSqlDatabase="true" >
</sessionState>
```

Can anyone please guide be in correcting the same ? All the other things in the website are pretty much working fine.

Below is some additional information:

---

To summarize, I have done the following.

1. Migrated a website to Windows Azure successfully
2. Created the required connection strings for the database access successfully.
3. Tested the website on the local machine using Compute Emulator and Storage Emulator.
4. When I published the website and uploaded the packageFile and configurationFile, everything was working fine in general. BUT

for the pages which used session/cookies. All static pages worked well. All database access were proper.

1. Then, I wrote some code for setting right the session.

GOT ERRORS AND ENTIRE WEBSITE STOPPED WORKING

1. Created the database and tables that were required (ASPSTATE database and its corresponding tables). Everything went well.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlazure/archive/2010/08/04/10046103.aspx

Tested the website ... Still getting the error on local and on cloud...as mentioned previously in this post.

Can you please guide me to rectify this.

Comment: FYI, this is also posted on the MSDN forums here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazuredevelopment/thread/ee996508-2401-49ae-ba4a-c3655dc918ac

Comment: Maybe you can check your connection string.  I vaguely remember more terms in it, especially with regards to disabling integrated security.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.Hey guys,

Thanks for the replies. I modified the session state in web.config a little and its as below

```
    <sessionState cookieless="false" mode="SQLServer" 
                  sqlConnectionString="data source=serverName.database.windows.net;user id=UserID@serverName;password=password;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;"
                  timeout="20"
                  allowCustomSqlDatabase="true">
    </sessionState>
```

Now its working fine.

Regards
Sandeep

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the SQL Server Session State Provider isn't throwing an exception, just not keeping state?

You'll be aware that a cookie is used to hold the session ID, so it may stem from a general cookie problem.

Are you doing anything unusual with domain names? I'm just wondering if there's a domain mismatch between the cookies and the URL through which you're accessing the site, meaning that the cookies don't get presented on subsequent requests.

Of course, it's also possible that a security limitation is preventing your browser accepting the cookies, but you'd likely have noticed that as an issue before now!