# Session value not returning correct in production

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, session

I have following code where return Json result to my view. I'm trying to format the currency as format stored in db.

```
        [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UpdateTaxAndGrandTotal()
    {
        try
        {
            string cf = SessionModel_ConfigData.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ConfigName == ConfigModel.CurrencyFormat).ConfigValue;
            cf = (cf != null) ? cf : "{0:c2}";
            double? total = SessionOrder.Sum(x => x.TotalPrice);
            double? totalTax = SessionOrder.Sum(x => x.TaxValue);


            return Json(new
            {
                success = true,
                message = "success",
                TotalTax = Resource.Resources.TotalTax.ToUpper() + ": " + string.Format(cf, totalTax),
                GrandTotal = Resource.Resources.GrandTotal.ToUpper() + ": " + string.Format(cf, total)
            });

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Json(new { success = false, message = ex.Message });
        }
    }
```

And the config data stored in session

```html
  private const string _SessionModel_ConfigData = "_SessionModel_ConfigData";
        public List<Config> SessionModel_ConfigData
        {
            get
            {
                if (Session[_SessionModel_ConfigData] == null)
                {
                    return (List<Config>)(Session[_SessionModel_ConfigData] = new List<Config>());
                }

                return Session[_SessionModel_ConfigData] as List<Config>;
            }
            set { }
        }
```

This works fine while debugging on local machine. But once hosted to Azure Service, the session doesn't seems to return the format. It just displays default format of {0:c2}

We enabled in proc session `<sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="30" />`

What could be wrong? Other sessions seems to be behaving fine.

Comment: **Try this link:**
[session and cookies issues on azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6868461/session-and-cookies-not-working-on-windows-azure-cloud-environment)

Comment: I have 3 sessions here. Other 2 works fine, only one having an issue. Why?